# VGG16: como usar camada Dense_2 como output - python

Tags: python, classificação, processamento-de-imagens, model, deep-learning

estou usando o modelo vgg16 para extração de características

https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/vgg16.py

chamo o mesmo através da função:

```
model = VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
```

Porém a função retorna a camada softmax, caso eu utilize o `include_top=False` tenho o retorno da ultima camada de convolução do VGG.

Como eu poderia fazer `model` receber a camada Dense 2 ?, no código não exste mais nenhum argumento que me de esse resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é gerar o VGG16 completo com todas as camadas, e depois selecionar a camada desejada com comando get_layer

```
modelo = VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
nome_camada = 'fc2' #Dense_2 do VGG16
camada_selecionada = Model(inputs=modelo.input, outputs=modelo.get_layer(nome_camada).output)
```